# Add a namespaces header in a SQL for XML query

Tags: sql-server, xml-namespaces, for-xml-path

I have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.Code AS Prime,
    t.nom AS Alfa,
    t.Nom AS Name,
    t.Adresse AS Street,
    t.CP AS ZipCode,
    t.Localite AS City, 
    CASE t.CodePays 
        WHEN NULL THEN 'BE' 
        WHEN '' THEN 'BE' 
        ELSE t.CodePays 
    END AS Country,
    CASE t.CodeLangue 
        WHEN 'NL' THEN 1 
        WHEN 'FR' THEN 2 
        WHEN 'EN' THEN 3 
        WHEN 'DE' THEN 4 
        ELSE 1 
    END AS Language,
    'EUR' AS CurrencyCode,
    CASE t.Tva WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VATCode,
    CASE t.Tva WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VATStatus,
    t.Tva AS VATNumber,
    CASE t.CodePays 
        WHEN NULL THEN 'BE' 
        WHEN '' THEN 'BE' 
        ELSE t.CodePays 
    END AS CountryVATNumber,
    0 AS Status /* 0=pas importé*/ 
FROM 
    tiers t 
INNER JOIN 
    tiersexport te ON t.code = te.code 
WHERE 
    t.CodeTypeTiers IN (1, 3)
ORDER BY 
    t.Code 
FOR XML PATH('Customer'), ROOT('Customers');
```

This generates me a proper XML:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer>
  ...
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I need instead to have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ImportExpMPlus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Customers>
        <Customer>
        ...
        </Customer>
    </Customers>
</ImportExpMPlus>
```

Can you tell me how to do this?

I tried

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.Code AS Prime,
    t.nom AS Alfa,
    t.Nom AS Name,
    t.Adresse AS Street,
    t.CP AS ZipCode,
    t.Localite AS City, 
    CASE t.CodePays 
        WHEN NULL THEN 'BE' 
        WHEN '' THEN 'BE' 
        ELSE t.CodePays 
    END AS Country,
    CASE t.CodeLangue 
        WHEN 'NL' THEN 1 
        WHEN 'FR' THEN 2 
        WHEN 'EN' THEN 3 
        WHEN 'DE' THEN 4 
        ELSE 1 
    END AS Language,
    'EUR' AS CurrencyCode,
    CASE t.Tva WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VATCode,
    CASE t.Tva WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VATStatus,
    t.Tva AS VATNumber,
    CASE t.CodePays 
        WHEN NULL THEN 'BE' 
        WHEN '' THEN 'BE' 
        ELSE t.CodePays 
    END AS CountryVATNumber,
    0 AS Status /* 0=pas importé*/ 
FROM 
    tiers t 
INNER JOIN 
    tiersexport te ON t.code = te.code 
WHERE 
    t.CodeTypeTiers IN (1, 3)
ORDER BY 
    t.Code 
FOR XML PATH('Customer'), ROOT('Customers');
```

but THEN I received this output:

```
<Customers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Customer>
      ...
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Comment: I need to have:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ImportExpMPlus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Customers>
               <Customer>
                   ...
               </Customer>
 </Customers>
</ImportExpMPlus>

Comment: Nobody here has your tables nor the data that they contain, so we can't replicate your problem. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75903646/edit) your question to include the desired XML output and the actual XML output you're getting so that we can see what the actual problem is that you're experiencing. Add the XML as fenced text, not screen shots.

Comment: Since the xml prolog `<?xml version="1..?>` is removed for the xml datatype in Sql Server and the encoding is set to ISO-8859-1, you could use varchar as the result of FOR XML, prepend the prolog& ImportExpMPlus and append /ImportExpMPlus with string concatenation.. https://dbfiddle.uk/bCT_-hQJ

Comment: If the problem is the lack of `ImportExpMPlus` as the root element, have you tried nesting your query to produce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the extra elements through variables, like this:

```
DECLARE @xml_header NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @xml_header = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>\n<ImportExpMPlus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">\n';
DECLARE @xml_footer NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @xml_footer = N'\n</ImportExpMPlus>';

DECLARE @xml_data NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @xml_data = (SELECT DISTINCT
                      t.Code AS Prime
                    , t.nom AS Alfa
                    , t.Nom AS Name
                    , t.Adresse AS Street
                    , t.CP AS ZipCode
                    , t.Localite AS City
                    , CASE t.CodePays WHEN NULL THEN 'BE' WHEN '' THEN 'BE' ELSE t.CodePays END AS Country
                    , CASE t.CodeLangue WHEN 'NL' THEN 1 WHEN 'FR' THEN 2 WHEN 'EN' THEN 3 WHEN 'DE' THEN 4 ELSE 1 END AS LANGUAGE
                    , 'EUR' AS CurrencyCode
                    , CASE t.Tva WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VATCode
                    , CASE t.Tva WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VATStatus
                    , t.Tva AS VATNumber
                    , CASE t.CodePays WHEN NULL THEN 'BE' WHEN '' THEN 'BE' ELSE t.CodePays END AS CountryVATNumber
                    , 0 AS STATUS
                FROM tiers t
                -- INNER JOIN tiersexport te ON t.code=te.code
                WHERE t.CodeTypeTiers IN (1, 3)
                ORDER BY t.Code
                FOR XML PATH('Customer')
                    , ROOT('Customers')
                )

SELECT @xml_header + @xml_data + @xml_footer
```

Note: I see no obvious purpose for the joined table `tiersexport` and maybe you can also get rid of `DISTINCT` because the join may be the cause of repeated rows.

see this dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/eNKqdjlY

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by Paul ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/75903833/7733418 ) I provide a variation which might be needed in some cases:
I for example needed some conversion from XML to nvarchar and back to make it work

```
SELECT @Xml1 = @xml_header + convert(nvarchar(max),@xml_data) + @xml_footer
select CONVERT(XML,@Xml1)
```

Comment: Please provide details on the situation in which this is needed. Why is it needed? How does it work? Why does it help?